# Clone a project from github using command line in linux

Tags: git

I'm new to both linux and github. I'm trying to learn and contribute to open source.

The first step I have done is, installed git using yum. Searched for a project I'm interested in and cloned using

git clone --bare

I see a folder with extension .git. I don't understand what is .git file. I'm expecting it to be the dump of the project. When I download it manually I get the project though.

So what is .git extension and how do I see the contents of the projects there.

Comment: Besides the correct answer @dwursteisen gave below: are you sure you want to _clone_ the project? Not download?

Comment: @arkascha what's the difference? clone is just a copy of the project in my local. correct me if am wrong. Also, how do I make commit from command line?

Comment: A download gives you the content of the project. A clone additionally allows to handle that content using git. So making commits and pushing. About your second question: I suggest you start reading the documentation: `man git`,`man git-commit` or/and read an introduction into git.

Comment: thanks, that helps. I was wondering how my local git is will commit changes to my account? how will it establish the authentication?

Comment: Just start reading the documentation. It is all explained in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use git clone without --bare

```
git clone https://...
```

Comment: It clone the repository as a repository (like github) and not like a working copy where you can edit/commit files

Comment: Any guide on how can I commit a file from command line? please let me know. thanks

Comment: @sython Instead of asking for a tutorial step-by-step on stackoverflow, why not read a book like [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)? It is free and contains answers to all the questions you are asking here, and many more.